# Queue Server that allows global consume rate for all workers

Tags: java, algorithm, message-queue, amqp

I have many tasks that my servers need to handle. these tasks must be handled at a specific given rate due to API call rate limit that the workers need to meet.

In order to guarantee that these tasks are not executed at a rate higher than the API rate limits, I would like to be able to configure the rate in which the queue sends messages for handling.

Additionally, that queue has to keep the ordering of the pushed messages and release them in FIFO order to provide fairness.

Lastly, It would be great if coding wise this will be kind transparent when used so that a client will my an API call to send the message to the queue and the same client will receive back the message after it is released by the queue according to the work rate and relevant order.  e.g. using RxJava

```
waitForMessageToBeReleased(message, queue)
     .subscribe(message -> // do some stuff)  // message received to the same 
client after it was released by the queue according to the defined work rate.
```

I am currently using Redis to control execution rate by creating a variable which has a specific amount of TTL and other calls wait until this variable expires. It does not, however, handle ordering and can cause clients to starve in case of a high load.

Comment: What's the maximum expected aggregated rate and per client?

Comment: I do not expect clients to aggregate requests. I was thinking of using some kind of queue which can be configured to aggregate according to expected load and use cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) is capable of supporting your use case with minimal effort.

Here is a strawman design that satisfies your requirements:

- Send signalWithStart request to a user workfow using userID as the workflow ID. It either delivers the signal to the workflow or first starts the workflow and delivers signal to it.
- All request to that workflow are buffered by it. Cadence provides hard gurantee that only one workflow with given ID can exist in open state. So all signals (events) are guaranteed to be buffered in the workflow that belongs to the user.
- An internal workflow event loop dispatches these requests one by one.
- When the buffer is empty workflow can complete.

Here is the workflow code that implements it in Java (Go client is also supported):

```
public interface SerializedExecutionWorkflow {

    @WorkflowMethod
    void execute();

    @SignalMethod
    void addTask(Task t);
}

public interface TaskProcessorActivity {
    @ActivityMethod
    void process(Task poll);
}

public class SerializedExecutionWorkflowImpl implements SerializedExecutionWorkflow {

    private final Queue<Task> taskQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final TaskProcesorActivity processor = Workflow.newActivityStub(TaskProcesorActivity.class);

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        while(!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
            processor.process(taskQueue.poll());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addTask(Task t) {
        taskQueue.add(t);
    }
}
```

And then the code that enqueues that task to the workflow through signal method:

```
private void addTask(WorkflowClient cadenceClient, Task task) {
    // Set workflowId to userId
    WorkflowOptions options = new WorkflowOptions.Builder().setWorkflowId(task.getUserId()).build();
    // Use workflow interface stub to start/signal workflow instance
    SerializedExecutionWorkflow workflow = cadenceClient.newWorkflowStub(SerializedExecutionWorkflow.class, options);
    BatchRequest request = cadenceClient.newSignalWithStartRequest();
    request.add(workflow::execute);
    request.add(workflow::addTask, task);
    cadenceClient.signalWithStart(request);
}
```

Cadence offers a lot of other advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.
- Distributed CRON support

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not fully clear how this answers all my requirements. I'll look into it

Comment: The basic idea is that Cadence supports rate limiting of task execution out of the box and the workflows are used to serialize the task execution for the given key as they are fully consistent.